# Сделать лишь часть области активной jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-events

Не могу сделать чтобы была лишь часть области была активной, а перемещался весь блок. К примеру есть **div main** внутри него еще два и нужно сделать так чтобы поменять родительсике блоки **(main)** местами можно было лишь перетаскивая первый внутрений **div** с класом **active**.

Потому что сейчас вся область **main** активная

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="active">Change<div>
    <div class="text">some text<div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="active">Change<div>
    <div class="text">some text<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Сделать лишь часть области активной jQuery sortable

Если посмотреть описание и примеры к `sortable` - ответ сразу найдется. ;)

**Перетаскивание за определенный элемент**

Если в списке нужно будет выделять и копировать текст, например в текстовых полях, то перемещение за всю область сделает это проблематичным. Поэтому делают перемещение кликнув по иконке, так можно сделать добавив параметр handle и указав в нем название ее класса.

```
<ul class="sortable-ul">
    <li>
        <i class="handle"></i> 
        Строка 1 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите текст">
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
 
<script>
$('.sortable-ul').sortable({
    handle: '.handle'
});
</script>
```

Более подробнее тут - https://snipp.ru/jquery/ui-sortable